# Laravel 5.4 Oracle database connection

Tags: php, laravel, oci8

I have installed fresh version of laravel 5.4 and I'm trying to use yajra/laravel-oci8 package to connect to my oracle db, I followed all the instructions provided but still i get this Error message " ***Call to undefined function Yajra\Pdo\oci_connect()*** " when I try to get data from my DB I've been struggling with this problem for 4 days and no luck, can u help please

Comment: Are you sure that oci8 is installed properly? Can you try a `php -m | grep oci8` and see what you get?

Comment: when i run php -m I cant find oci8 in the list!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think it means that oci8 extension was added twice in you php.ini and/or in another ini file loaded by php. Double check you cli config and make sure it's not added multiple times.

Exactly, use now:

`;extension=php_oci8_11g.dll ;` Use with Oracle 11gR2 Instant Client

```
extension=php_oci8.dll
```

Comment: I use wamp server and I dont have "extension=php_oci8.dll" in php.ini it's extension=php_oci8_12c.dll and it's already uncommented , is that a problem